# want to include Fragments under tabFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which has navigation drawer and tabview with viewPager.
I want to open some fragments inside the tabview according to the selection in the navigation drawer. this is how i navigate to fragments according to the selection

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.ap) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new FpFragment()).commit();

            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.vfp) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new VeryFinFrag()).commit();
            }
```

Is it possible??

Comment: have you tried the code?

Comment: yes, It opens fragments as different activities i dont want that. i need to view the all the fragments under the tab view

Comment: You need to decide on using only one of them. Either load all your fragments to the viewpager and use the viewpager for navigation or Use the Navigation drawer and replace the content of a container in your activity.